# prove if $b \geq a$, then $a^{b} \geq b^a$

Tags: proof-writing, induction

I found that if b = a - 1, then $a^{b} \leq b^{a}$ and if a = b, then $a^{b} = b^{a}$ for obvious reasons. Now, i'm having a hard time figuring out how to prove that if $b \geq a$, then $a^{b} \geq b^a$. I have a few test cases that work but obviously i need to prove this inductively. Any help?  also this works for a $\geq$ 4

Comment: $a,b$ are in $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: yes they are in the set of naturals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

Prove and use that the function $x\mapsto \frac{x}{\ln x}$ is increasing on $[e,+\infty)$

Comment: is there a way to prove this without the use of limits?

Comment: didn't use this answer...found how to do it without limits but thanks anyways :^)

Comment: Then answer your own question, you can do that and would help others.